# Update viewmodel in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to update my model that is bound to my view based on a user action (selecting a value in a dropdownlistbox). I can get the model using this `var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` I can access the view model and update the properties but when I submit the form my model binding doesn't have my changes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Show your html generated. What viewModel looks like in client site?

Comment: The properties that I want to update are not generated in the view but they are in the model that is bound to the view.

Comment: How do you want to manage changes in Client Side with jquery?

Comment: I figured it out. On the change event of the dropdownlistbox. I get the model as JSON `var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` then I update the properties in the viewModel then I ajax post it the to controller.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use AJAX to send the updated object to the server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // we serialize the model as a javascript object
    var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

    // we do some updates
    viewModel.Foo = 'bar';

    // and we post the model back to the server:
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(viewModel),
        success: function(result) {
            // do some processing based on the result
            // returned by the controller action
        }
    });
</script>
```